# Identity not integrable on surface measure

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In my textbook in the definition of center of mass there is a following assumtpion:

Let $S \in \mathbb R^m$ be a differentiable manifold such that $l_S(S) < \infty $ and the identity map on $\mathbb R^m$ is $l_S$-integrable on $S$.

I don't see why the second assumption is necessary here. Is there such a differentiable manifold of finite surface measure where $id$ of $\mathbb R^m$ is not integrable with respect to the surface measure?

Comment: If $S$ is bounded, then $\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$ will be integrable on $S$ (bounded measurable functions on finite measure spaces are integrable). However, if you merely assume that $S$ has finite surface area (and unbounded), then there's no reason for the identity map to be integrable.

Comment: I don't get it; can you give any example?

Comment: can you think of examples of surfaces with finite surface area but unbounded?

Comment: as a further hint, think of flat regions in the plane. As an even further hint, note that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\infty$ but $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx<\infty$.

Comment: But isn't the surface measure of S just the pullback of id on $\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: I mean its evaluation

Comment: The surface measure is obtained by pulling back via the inclusion map, of the Riemannian metric on $R^m$ to $S$ and making a measure from the induced metric.

Comment: Anyway for a concrete counter example, just forget about surface measures. Can you think of a subset of the plane which has finite area but is unbounded? I already gave you a hint above.

Comment: Obviously it's trivial to find such a subset, but I don't see why the identity pullback would be not integrable there... why would I forget about surface measure? It clearly must be $l_S$ integrable, so hard to find a counterexample without thinking about surface measure

Comment: Forget about surface measures mumbo jumbo because the surface measure of an open subset of the plane is simply the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Did you try to work out my hint?